# Rails: Convert future meeting time in one time zone to another time zone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Using flatpickr, I allow the user to specify the time and date of a future meeting that includes their time zone.

The result is the following value:

`Mon May 25 2020 12:00:00 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time)`

They can choose a team member to meet with and that time member will have set their current time zone and I'm storing that value using ActiveSupport::TimeZone (https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html)

I am trying to figure out how to take the date result above and display to the user who is scheduling the meeting, "It will be 7pm for X."

I send the attendeeZone and meetingTime to a Rails endpoint:

```
  def time_for_attendee

    attendeeZone = params["attendeeZone"]
    # => "Tokyo"

    meetingTime = params["meetingTime"]
    # => "Mon May 25 2020 12:00:00 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time)"

    attendeeTime = ???

    render json: {
      attendeeZone: attendeeZone,
      meetingTime: meetingTime,
      attendeeTime: attendeeTime
     }

  end
```

How would I convert that meetingTime to the attendeeTime based on their time zone?

I got close with `Time.zone.now.in_time_zone(attendeeZone)` but I'm not sure how to convert the format of meetingTime to replace `now`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `.parse()`

```
Time.zone.parse(params["meetingTime"]).in_time_zone(attendeeZone)
```

Alternatively, if you assign it to a model, then it will be parsed automatically already.

Comment: Thanks, this got it! What do you mean by "assign it to a model then it will be parsed automatically"?

Comment: Since you're using rails, I assumed you're using activerecord. Meeting time sounds like something that should be stored to a database. If you have a datetime column on a model, then you can just pass the unparsed string representation into that column and rails will convert it for you. Then you don't need to call .parse yourself.